# cannot find bits/mathcalls.h

Tags: c, makefile

Hi I trying to create C executables where I seem to be having trouble locating "bits/mathcalls.h".

```
$ make

45) cannot find include file "bits/mathcalls.h"
        not in /usr/include/linux/bits/mathcalls.h
        not in include/bits/mathcalls.h
        not in /usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h
```

However using find

```
$ sudo find / -name 'mathcalls.h'
/usr/include/mathcalls.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h
```

so it does exist, but not in any of the locations "make" is looking in. how do I add these paths so that "make" looks for them where I actually have them?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never include `bits/mathcalls.h` directly. You should always only include `math.h` it will then include the correct `mathcalls.h` for your target OS/architecture. In fact if you open and read any of the `mathcalls.h` headers that you have they will have in their first couple lines something along the likes of

```
#ifndef _MATH_H
# error "Never include <bits/mathcalls.h> directly; include <math.h> instead."
#endif
```

Which will throw an error if you actually try to include them without `math.h`.

Comment: L - have called math.h instead.